# Problema com regex para UserAgent Android

Tags: php, regex, user-agent

Estou tentando criar uma regex ( para usar em PHP ) que consiga casar os grupos corretamente e extrair as informações que preciso. Neste caso é para obter informações de useragent android.

Quando o userAgent é assim:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; SM-G530BT Build/LRX22G; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36

da certo, porém tem userAgent que tem um dado a mais, o "pt-br" , como esse:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; pt-br; LG-E467f Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

eu não consegui porque o "pt-br" é opcional.

Segue o que ja tentei
https://regex101.com/r/6TRsM2/1

meu regex é este:

```
(?P<browser>Android)\s(?P<major_version>\d+)\.(?P<minor_version>\d+\.?\d?);(?P<lang>\spt-br)?(?P<device>[ \w\-?]+)\s
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a concluir esse regex? sendo que preciso que ele case com todos os grupos, e quando não tiver o pt-br, apenas retorne vazio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar essa Regex

```
(?P<browser>Android)\s(?P<major_version>\d+)\.(?P<minor_version>\d+\.?\d?);(?P<lang>\spt-br){0,1};{0,1}(?P<device>[ \w\-?]+)\s
```

[Você pode testar o funcionamento dela aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/6TRsM2/2)

**O que eu fiz de diferente?**
eu incluí `{0,1}` após o `[...](?P<lang>\spt-br)` e `;{0,1}` tornando opcional a existência de `pt-br;` após o minor version, agora ele irá capturar somente caso exista o pt-br.

**Considerações**
Não sei se existe a possibilidade, porém é bom considerar a existência de outros browsers e outras lang's, caso tenha essa possibilidade use o operador "OU" (`|`) [como neste exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/6TRsM2/3).

Comment: Você tem razão, não me lembrei de que outras linguagens podem vir ou mesmo outra estrutura de user agent. O ideal era uma que casasse com qualquer lang que vier. Mas no momento, para o que preciso deu certo. Obrigado.